# 1-of-1 NFT in a collection of Solana

Tags: nft, nfts, candymachine

I am working on a project where we generated artwork using Hash Lips artwork generator but we need 1 special/Legendary NFT within our collection.
Is there any way we can define an nft special?
I have done some research and I found we cannot do it automatically.
It needs to be done manuall as mentioned here.
[Github issues link](https://github.com/HashLips/hashlips_art_engine/issues/1126)

Answer (score 1):

1/1 are special or unique art designed by the artist.

Comment: Yes I know but I think the question is how we can do that?

Comment: It's a NFT with different attributes. If you check out Y00ts for example. All the 1/1 have a special Image + an attribute called 1/1.